# Parse a markdown-like string into an array of text fragments with style properties

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, markdown

I'm about to parse the following markdown-like string into the below data structure:

```
"The _big_ dog is *nice*. _*Bang!*_ No_1."

[
  {text: "The "},
  {text: "big", underline: true},
  {text: " dog is "},
  {text: "nice", bold: true},
  {text: " "},
  {text: "Bang!", underline: true, bold: true},
  {text: " No_1."}
]
```

I'd say there must be some back tracing involved. This could be implemented with regular expressions. The one for the 'underline' part could be `/\b_([^_]+)_\b/` . We only want to match them, when the there's a word boundary around it, hence the `No_1` in the example which should not be underline. It turns out that this doesn't work that easily for the `*` part, so I'm using another approach below. But the main problem remains is how to plumb things together.

One regex match doesn't do it, a while loop with `.exec` looked more promising: The below code is not working correctly yet, however it might show how I currently think about the problem:

```
function f (str) {
    const underline = "(?:^| )_([^_]+)_(?:$| )";
    const bold = "(?:^| )\\*([^*]+)\\*(?:$| )";
    const goOn = "([^_*]+)"

    const xs = [];
    const regex = new RegExp(underline + "|" + bold + "|" + goOn, 'g');

    while ((result = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        [all, u, b, g] = result;
        u && xs.push({ text: u, underline: true});
        b && xs.push({ text: b, bold: true});
        g && xs.push({ text: g});
    }

    return xs;
}
```

Could anybody give me a hint how to solve this properly?

Comment: What's the supposed result for intersecting groups? like `The _very *big* dog_ is nice.` or `The *very _big* dog_ is nice.`

Comment: very good question. In cases you have opening and closing delimeters, this is mostly an invalid thing. Here, it might be interpreted as valid, but I'd say: it depends on what is easier to parse.

Comment: The CommonMark spec includes a [description](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#phase-2-inline-structure) of an algorithm to parse inline markup into a syntax tree. No code, just a long-form explanation. You may find that useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var input = "The _big_ dog is *nice*. _*Bang!*_ No_1.";

function f(str) {
  var splittedStr = str.split(' ');
  var outputArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < splittedStr.length; i++) {
    var text = splittedStr[i];
    var outputArrRow = {
      text: text.replace(/\*?_?\*?\b/g, '').replace(/\b\*?_?\*?/g, '')
    };
    if ((text.match(/_/g) || []).length > 1) { // If more than two occurrences of _ in the text.
      outputArrRow.underline = true;
    }
    if ((text.match(/\*/g) || []).length > 1) { // If more than two occurrences of * in the text.
      outputArrRow.bold = true;
    }
    outputArr.push(outputArrRow);
  }
  return outputArr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(input)));
```

It returns:

```
[
    {"text": "The"},
    {"text": "big", "underline": true},
    {"text": "dog"},
    {"text": "is"},
    {"text": "nice.", "bold": true},
    {"text": "Bang!", "underline": true, "bold": true},
    {"text": "No_1."}
]
```

This is a bit incomplete because it doesn't fully handle for multi-word italics or bold, but it does satisfy your criteria. Update your question and let me know if you have any more criteria that this doesn't pass.

<sub>(This doesn't return the `{text: " "}` element, but I couldn't find a pattern of when to return or not return this)</sub>

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution that supports multi-word, any ideas?

Comment: Post another question with more specifics on correct and incorrect output, and I'll have a look @NirH

Comment: Posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213330/js-parse-markdown-string-bold-and-italic-only-into-an-array-of-text-style