# js - Parse markdown string (bold and italic only) into an array of text + style jsons

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

Trying to parse a string in javascript that contains bold annotations, marked as `*multi word bold*` (asterisk), and italic annotations, marked as `_multi word italic_` (underline).
I'd like the parser function to support **multi words** annotations, italic within bold, bold within italic and mixed (see examples).

Here are some inputs with required outputs examples:

```
const simpleInput = "The *quick brown fox* jumps _over the lazy dog_";
const simpleOutput =[
    {text: 'The '},
    {text: 'quick brown fox', bold: true},
    {text: ' jumps '},
    {text: 'over the lazy dog', italic: true}
];

const italicWithinBoldInput = "The *quick brown _fox jumps_ over the* lazy dog";
const italicWithinBoldOutput =[
    {text: 'The '},
    {text: 'quick brown ', bold: true},
    {text: 'fox jumps', bold: true, italic: true},
    {text: ' over the', bold: true},
    {text: ' lazy dog'}
];

const mixedInput = "The *quick brown _fox jumps* over the_ lazy dog";
const mixedOutput =[
    {text: 'The '},
    {text: 'quick brown ', bold: true},
    {text: 'fox jumps', bold: true, italic: true},
    {text: ' over the', italic: true},
    {text: ' lazy dog'}
];
```

I tried some parsers on npm but everything was a bit of an overkill, nothing was quite what I needed..

Comment: In the last example you are using `_fox jumps_` as text of your third object despite the mixedInput not containing that string. Is that an error?

Comment: @MattNewelski you're right, fixing

Comment: Another question: since you are setting flags of `bold` and `italic` on strings, why is it necessary to include the underscores in the output string? I don't know what the purpose of this exercise is, but if you are setting these flags to then parse it again anyway and wrap that text in some tags then I would absolutely suggest doing regex and replacements on the input string instead.

Comment: Check the edit, I removed the underlines. This is not an exercise, I'm mapping this array into react-native elements later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```js
function getObject(str){
    let bold = false, italics = false;
    let output = [];
    let text = str.split('').reduce((a, b) => {
        if(b == '*'){
            if(bold){
                if(a != ''){
                    if(italics)
                        output.push({text: a, bold: true, italics:true});
                    else
                      output.push({text: a, bold: true});
                }
                bold = false;
            }
            else{
                if(italics)
                    output.push({text: a, italics: true})
                else
                    output.push({text: a})
                bold = true;
            }
            return '';
        }
        else if(b == '_'){
            if(italics){
                if(a != ''){
                    if(bold)
                        output.push({text: a, bold: true, italics:true});
                    else
                      output.push({text: a, italics: true});
                }
                italics = false;
            }
            else{
                if(bold)
                    output.push({text: a, bold: true})
                else
                    output.push({text: a})
                italics = true;
            }
            return '';
        }
        else{
            return a+b;
        }
    }, '');
    if(text != '')
        output.push({text : text});
    console.log(output);
    return output;
}


const simpleInput = "The *quick brown fox* jumps _over the lazy dog_";

getObject(simpleInput);

const italicWithinBoldInput = "The *quick brown _fox jumps_ over the* lazy dog";

getObject(italicWithinBoldInput);

const mixedInput = "The *quick brown _fox jumps* over the_ lazy dog";

getObject(mixedInput);
```

Comment: Thanks! Did the job.

Comment: Good example! A thing to note is that the code works for the example texts provided but is not compatible with `CommonMark` where example texts would be *Italic*.

https://commonmark.org/help/

Comment: I'm wondering if this has worst-case quadratic behaviour? It seems like if you pass in a string without asterisks or underscores, the function concatenates the input to an empty string one character at a time. I don't know whether JS string concatenation under the hood does something clever which avoids O(n^2) complexity for this use case.